# WooCommerce - How to check particular product is in cart or not. Any Hook?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any hook, to check any particular product is added to cart or not ?

Answer (score 6):

You can find an item in the cart with the [`find_product_in_cart()`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#779-802) method of `WC_Cart`. You'll need to generate a `$cart_id` using [`generate_cart_id()`](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#804-842), in order to do this:

```
$product_id = 123456;  // Some product id
$product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );

// Returns an empty string, if the cart item is not found
$in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );

if ( $in_cart ) {
    // Do something if the product is in the cart
} else {
    // Do something if the product is not in the cart
}
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me, however the following linked solution did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816448/disable-all-payments-gateway-if-theres-specifics-products-in-the-cart