# Disable all payments gateway if there's specifics products in the Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, cart

I  would like to disable all payments gateways under special situation: 
I've 2 special products that I don't want to be combined at checkout with any other product.

Lets say that my **"special"** products IDs are **`496`** and **`484`**. All other are **"normal"** products.

1. if one of these **"special"** products is in the cart, I want to disable "paypal" for example.
2. if a customer has in his cart, at once, a **"special"** product and a **"normal"** product, I want to disable **all the payments gateway**, so he can't checkout.

This is my code:

```
//disable add to cart if
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_gateways', 1);

function filter_gateways( $gateways )
{   
    global $woocommerce;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {   
        // store product IDs in array   
        $nonPPproducts = array(496,484);        

        if (in_array( $values['product_id'], $nonPPproducts ) ) {
            unset($gateways['cod'], $gateways['bacs'], $gateways['cheque'], $gateways['stripe']);
        } elseif ( in_array( $values['product_id'], $nonPPproducts ) && in_array( $values['product_id'] ) ) {           
            unset($gateways['under-review'], $gateways['cod'], $gateways['bacs'], $gateways['cheque'], $gateways['stripe']);
        }
    }

    return $gateways;   
}
```

But I can't figure out why the only first if statement works… In other words whatever the situation, all payment gateways are disabled except **`under-review`** payment gateway.

What I am doing wrong?
How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: 1) using global variables; 2) using hard coded values is not recommended. You could also create 2 *wrapper* functions in the last `if` for the `unset` with a meaningful name ..

Comment: just curious, have you considered not allowing it to be added to the cart or warn when trying to add it to the cart? The idea is to let the customer know as soon as possible that they cannot have the order in one cart rather than spending time shoppin' then being told they have to do it again.

Comment: @RyanVincent, would be even cool if i could do that

Comment: @LoicTheAztec sorry for the late vote different time zones :), your answer worked flawlessly without changing a single letter, thanks a lot

Comment: @AhmedNabil Yes it is also possible (what RyanVincent tell), like auto remove a product from cart with similar conditions and give an error notice to the customer. But this is not part of this question and you could ask another question, including your actual working code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Updated for WooCommerce 3+

First I think  that **`in_array( $values['product_id'] )`** in your code is not working as a correct condition and so your else statement is never "true". Then as a customer can have many items in his cart, depending on customer successive choices, with your code there will be many redundant **gateway unsets**…

Here it is your code revisited *(you will need to put the desire unset gateways in each statement)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_gateways', 1);
function filter_gateways( $gateways ){
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $gateways;

    // Storing special product IDs in an array
    $non_pp_products = array( 496, 484 );

    // Needed variables
    $is_non_prod = false;
    $is_prod = false;
    $count = 0;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // count number of items if needed (optional) 
        $count++;
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        if( ! empty($product) ){
            $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;
            if ( in_array( $product_id, $non_pp_products ) && ! $is_non_prod ) 
                $is_non_prod = true;

            if ( !in_array( $product_id, $non_pp_products ) && !$is_prod )
                $is_prod = true;

        }
    }
    if ( $is_non_prod && ! $is_prod ) // only special products 
    {
        // unset only paypal;
        unset( $gateways['paypal'] );
    } 
    elseif ( $is_non_prod && $is_prod ) // special and normal products mixed
    {
        // unset ALL GATEWAYS
        unset( $gateways['cod'], 
               $gateways['bacs'], 
               $gateways['cheque'], 
               $gateways['paypal'], 
               $gateways['stripe'], 
               $gateways['under-review'] );
    }
    elseif ( ! $is_non_prod && $is_prod ) // only normal products (optional)
    {
        // (unset something if needed)
    }
    return $gateways; 
}
```

*Naturally this code goes on functions.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

Comment: Be careful get_cart() causes problems (breaks menus and causes fatal error) if it is executed in the admin area so wrap everything in a conditional:  if( ! is_admin() ) { }

Comment: @AJD You are right, I have updated the code. Thanks.