# How to disable Cash on Delivery on some specific products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, cart

I want to disable Cash on Delivery(COD) for some products on my online shopping site.

Is it Possible?

Comment: Simple search in google! Read this article -- https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-payment-method-for-specific-category/

Answer (score 7):

> Compatible with woocommerce version 3+

Based on "[Disable all payments gateway if there's specifics products in the Cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816448/disable-all-payments-gateway-if-theres-specifics-products-in-the-cart/38817822#38817822)".

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditionally_disable_cod_payment_method', 10, 1);
function conditionally_disable_cod_payment_method( $available_gateways ){
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    // HERE define your Products IDs
    $products_ids = array(37,40,53);

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // Compatibility with WC 3+
        $product_id = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? $cart_item['data']->id : $cart_item['data']->get_id();
        if (in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $products_ids ) ){
            unset($available_gateways['cod']);
            break; // As "COD" is removed we stop the loop
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to use [`woocommerce_available_payment_gateways`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_available_payment_gateways/) filter.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'show_hide_cod', 10, 1);

function show_hide_cod($gateways)
{
    //list of product id to exclude COD
    $product_id_list = [12, 34];
    $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    foreach ($items as $item => $values)
    {
        $_product = $values['data']->post;
        if (in_array($_product->ID, $product_id_list))
        {
            unset($gateways['cod']);
        }
    }
    return $gateways;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.
Please Note: *I have't tested this code.*