# WooCommerce programmatically get Cart Id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am developing a plugin for WooCommerce.

On my backend API server (not my Wordpress server but another server that maintains a duplicate of the cart record) I need a way to tell if the cart I am dealing with is the same cart as before  (the cart items or details could have changed, but as far as the consumer who is using my WP site can tell they are still in the same shopping cart experience).

I need something that will serve as a unique identifier for the shopping cart.

As far as I can see there is no explicit ID on the [WC_Cart](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html) object,
Is there a good sensible way to derive one?

---

**Note:** I know it is possible to use [generate_cart_id()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#804-842) to get a unique ID for the product line in the cart (as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551789/woocommerce-how-to-check-particular-product-is-in-cart-or-not-any-hook)), however what I am looking for here is **an identifier for the cart itself**.

Comment: This is not a duplicate - I am looking for a cart id, not a line id

Comment: That's the only Cart ID showing up on the whole plugin code...

Comment: You are correct - there is no obvious cart ID in the plugin code - I have looked at what is available in the WC_Cart object before posting this question -- I will update the question again to make that more clear

Comment: I checked the code and researched SO before marking it as duplicate. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your objective is rather interesting. I've read the code of WooCommerce but sadly it does not have what you need.

I have a suggestion though. This might help. In `woocommerce_init` change `WC()->cart` with your own class that extends to `WC_Cart`. Then in your class have a way to set your cart id. Something like below.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'woocommerce_init', 30 );
function woocommerce_init() {
    class myWC_Cart extends WC_Cart {

        private $cart_id = 1234; // set cart id by any means necessary

        public function get_cart_id() {
            return $this->cart_id;
        }
    }
    WC()->cart = new myWC_Cart();
}
```

This way, anywhere WooCommerce is ready or loaded, you can get the cart id by calling
 `WC()->cart->get_cart_id();`

Comment: brilliant solution!    I'm not going to accept it just yet in case something else comes through ... but this seems like a very clean and sensible approach.

Comment: Also .. what would be a tidy way of saving the cart id against the cart object in the DB?

Comment: That I don't know. Maybe user_id? That totally depends on how you would use it.

Comment: This throws a fatal error on the admin page for me. Apparently, this way the session is not started and the cart resets everytime.

Comment: You probably don't need the cart on admin pages, so wrap it in an `is_admin()` check

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I am facing a similar situation for a client.

I am solving it storing the ID in session and checking the session variable anywhere I need it.

```
$new_cart = WC()->session->get('new_cart');
if( is_null($new_cart) ) {
    WC()->session->set('new_cart', uniqid());
}
```

I like Reigel solution but I and a bit afraid of extending core classes

Comment: Shouldn't that be `WC()->session->set('new_cart', uniqid());`?